# Quem é responsável pelo CSV?

Tags: csv, independente-de-linguagem

Uma pergunta curiosa e interessante que nunca vi veio na minha mente. No caso do Markdown, existe o CommonMark que é responsável pela implementação do Markdown que é o formato de arquivo e linguagem de marcação de texto legível pra humanos. No caso do PDF, existe o pdf-association que é responsável pela implementação e formato de arquivo PDF. Bem como JS, que é o grupo do Ecmascript chamado de TC39. Como podemos ver existem muitas comunidades e grupos responsáveis por alguma tecnologia. Ps: No caso do Linux tem a Linux Foundation que faz as certificações, cursos e mais algumas coisas relacionadas a linux, rede etc.  Também existem outras comunidades responsáveis por determinada tecnologia, licença como no caso da GPL que é um tipo licença de open source que é gerenciada por Gnu ou é OpenSource.com ou é a Free Foundation. Aqui no Brasil temos a Academia de Letras que é responsável pela norma culta, gramática etc. Bem como se você escreve artigos científicos existem normas técnicas como no caso da ABNT etc. A ABNT  é responsável pela padronização de documentos técnicos no Brasil.

Minha dúvida está relacionada aos fatos que mencionei anteriormente: "Uma pergunta curiosa e interessante que nunca vi veio na minha mente...." Minha dúvida seria quem é responsável pelo CSV?

Comment: A instituição normatizadora  é o [IETF | Internet Engineering Task Force](https://www.ietf.org/) o formato é documentado na [RFC 4180](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180).

Comment: A conversa se estendeu e foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138195/discussion-on-question-by-eduardo-mascarenhas-jose-quem-e-responsavel-pelo-csv) - para prosseguir, utilizem o link fornecido